# Is it cross-browser safe to send a 302 redirect back to the same page you are on?

Tags: http, cross-browser

In certain cases, I want to send a 302 redirect back to the same page.  For example, if I have a random datastore error, I could redirect them to the same page, having them automatically retry.

I tested this in firefox and chrome and it works fine, I'm wondering if I'll encounter problems in other browsers though.

Comment: FWIW, despite everyone telling you not to do this (and I tend to agree), this sort of thing is in use on some major websites. The one thing you MUST do is ensure that headers on the 302 indicate that the response isn't cacheable. You also probably want to ensure the headers on the current page are such that it's not cacheable either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect this to work in general. The [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) just says

> A client SHOULD detect infinite redirection loops,

but nothing about how it this must be done. It would be perfectly within the standard to detect at the first redirect that there's a cycle and immediately error out.

(Also, since you're the server, why not just do the retrying yourself?)

Comment: @dlambin: fair enough. I've edited to make the conclusion more explicit.

Comment: I'm not retrying server side because I'm on App Engine and there is a 30 second limit to the time you can spend servicing a request. This could be hit in certain cases.  Maybe I'll just append an unused query string variable to the url I say to redirect to. That should work right?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot rely on the idea that ANY browser will reload a page given a 302 to the same path. Some will follow the HTTP spec and choose not to retry the request, instead telling the user that it has encountered an infinite redirect loop.
For this reason you might be better off using a JavaScript location redirect.

Ultimately you should let the user's request wait for a response as long as needed to get the correct response. So if you can't get to the datastore, your webapp should be holding off on answering the request until either it can get to the datastore and form the response or it times out at some threshold you choose and tells the user it had an error, say 500 or 404.

Recall that a 404 is not GONE (410) and "a 404 error indicates that the requested resource may be available again in the future." A [503](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4) might interest you for your issue.

Comment: 404 also indicates, by virtue of its first digit, that the client is to be blamed for the failure. As that is not the case here, the appropriate response is something from the 5xx series.

Comment: My perspective is that all error codes indicate an error the user will blame on the server. Blame is not in the language of the spec: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5